# How to dynamically populate a shortcode option with the current product ID (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, function

How can I create a custom function in WP to dynamically populate a shortcode option with the product ID for the current product?  I figured out how to echo the shortcode (using do_shortcode) on all single product pages, but I need to include the current product's ID in the shortcode so that it only shows info relevant for the current product.

Example: Here is the shortcode used for a specific product (where 3462 is the product ID): [product_table include="3462"]

What code snippet would I need to place in my functions to grab the current product ID, and what corresponding text would go inside the quotes in the shortcode itself?

Obviously, I'm very new to this and still learning, so I would appreciate your patience with me :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using this shortcode on the product page and do you want the ID of the product your currently viewing?

Comment: Yes to both, the shortcode will be used on a custom layout made with Beaver Themer, and the shortcode needs to pull the current product's ID.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the WooCommerce product ID using their global variable `$product`.

```php
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
```

Or, you can use the WooCommerce method `wc_get_product()` get the product.

`$id = wc_get_product()->get_id();`

Lastly, you could retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

`$id = get_the_ID();`

**TLDR;**

Try this code:

```php
global $product;
echo do_shortcode( '[product_table include="' . $product->get_id() . '"]' );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's partly working.  In my original post  I was thinking that I would be able to use the shortcode as per normal (just in the HTML), so for clarity's sake I didn't include the whole thing.  What you provided is working when used in conjunction with a PHP snippet plugin, but once I add in all the shortcode options, it breaks.

Comment: Here's the complete shortcode I need to use with options:

[product_table include="54150" variations="separate" columns="name,price,stock,add-to-cart" cart_button="checkbox" show_quantity="true" links="none" page_length="false" search_box="false" reset_button="false" totals="false"]

How would I make that work?

Comment: @Grid It sounds like this is evolving into a new question; I answered the original question of "how to dynamically populate a shortcode with the product ID." I can't troubleshoot why the [product_table] shortcode ins't working without more detail of the code used and specific errors as a result.